# Is a company obligated to answer investor emails?

Tags: stocks

I wrote to a public company twice and did not receive an answer, so I wanted to know if such companies have obligation to answer investor questions?

Comment: I believe the answer is "no" in general, though there may be specific kinds of questions they have to answer in the annual meeting or other yearly statements, and of course the answer may be in something they have already published. Want to make your question more specific?

Comment: It also depends on countries and the regulation from the company law board, securities commission or equivalent.

Comment: @keshlam I am not sure how to be more specific. I just want to ask a company what are their plans for gathering funds and/or product development. Company is US based.

Comment: No company will ever tell you what their plans are until they are ready to make a public announcement, for reasons ranging from competitive to legal. Being a minor stockholder does not get you any special access. Sorry, but that letter was probably discarded upon arrival as inherently unreasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a small investor it is unlikely they will bother to answer you. But for a big investor (20% of the stock) they would know you, you would have personally meet the top management and they would reply to you.

If you are a small investor in a big company, the best solution if you want to be heard or have questions answered is to team up with all the other small investor so all of you combined reprensent a significant % of the stock value.

I don't think there is an obligation to answer but it could be the case for some countries.